# Integração VBA com IE, retornar Valor onde Value=""

Tags: javascript, aplicação-web, vba, macro, value

Tenho um problema em uma macro para me retornar o valor de uma página da Web, minha dúvida se estabelece mediante que o valor apresentado no código HTML sempre é nulo, porém na caixa de resposta me dá o valor requisitado. Mesmo após realizar a pesquisa não há alteração do valor value="", a página e um site estático **jsp**.

Já tentei n combinações, porém a macro "empaca" nesta parte, ele não me retorna nenhum valor.
Código abaixo:
    class="campo txt_velmaxima">
    Velocidade máxima:

Comment: Resto do código.
class="campo txt_velmaxima">
           <label for="lat_txt_velmaxima">Velocidade máxima:</label>
           <input type="text" name="lat_txt_velmaxima" id="lat_txt_velmaxima" disabled="disabled" value="" readonly="readonly" />

Comment: Parece que faltou o resto do códgo, tente editar novamente.

Comment: A base seria somente esta parte do código, e nela que está o problema, não tenho como retirar o Valor, porque como pode ver o valor, mesmo que faça a busca é nulo, ele está instanciando o valor diretamente para a página sem passar pelo código HTML, por isso estou procurando uma forma, de através do VBA excel, puxar o valor que é colocado em um textbox na página, a sim já foi tentando n combinações de IE.document.getelement....